# How do I display a website written in Dash as a static PDF (Python)?

Tags: python, flask, plotly, plotly-dash

I want to export the site I've made in dash into a static PDF. Here is the code for my site (it's just a chart with 3 columns):

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pdfkit
from flask import Flask, render_template, make_response

app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div(
                className="three columns",
                children=html.Div([
                    dcc.Graph(
                        id='right-top-graph',
                        figure={
                            'data': [{
                                'x': [1, 2, 3],
                                'y': [3, 1, 2],
                                'type': 'bar'
                            }],
                            'layout': {
                                'height': 400,
                                'margin': {'l': 10, 'b': 20, 't': 0, 'r': 0}
                            }
                        }
                    ),


                ])
            )

app.css.append_css({
    'external_url': 'https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css'
})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I tried using pdfkit by adding this code to my script, but it didn't work (received an error telling me that render_template() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given):

```
rendered = render_template('pdf_template.html',app)
pdf = pdfkit.from_string(rendered, False)
response = make_response(pdf)
response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=output.pdf'
```

**Does anyone have any idea as to how I can convert my dash site into a PDF?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: render_template takes only one positional argument.

Comment: Hi, did anyone get answer for this problem? right now I have to generate pdf from dash page, but internet solution doesnt work, either I can download pdf but I cannot open or I even cannot download pdf

Answer (score 3):

You can use the print function of whatever browser you are using (usually control + p) and save it as PDF if all you are looking for is the static PDF file.

If you want more enhanced functionality you can add a *print to PDF* button like the one in one of the dash [examples](https://dash-gallery.plotly.host/dash-vanguard-report). It uses a js file to invoke the browser print functionality, see [more detail](https://community.plot.ly/t/how-does-the-print-pdf-button-works-in-vanguard-report/14086/2). This way you can also use CSS to define the way the PDF output looks

The problem with using the python file to generate pdf directly is that dash only creates a JSON representation of the layout tree which is then assembled in the browser itself, see [more](https://github.com/plotly/dash/issues/145).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [pdfkit](https://pypi.org/project/pdfkit/) in the following way:

```
import pdfkit
pdfkit.from_url('http://local.dash.site', 'out.pdf')
```

The big difference from what you posted is that you could use the local web server to render the page.

As an alternative, you could also use https://wkhtmltopdf.org/
This is the lib underneath pdfkit.

Comment: I got the a traceback error and the following message: "INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s)." It seems to be searching for a wkhtmltopdf executable. Will look into where this is.

Comment: Dash is synchronous. How would you go about executing this code? I found ``async-dash`` library, but would prefer to solve it directly with the ``dash`` library.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the directions from the following link to create pdf:
http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/68/

render_template accepts only one positional arguments, the rest must be **keyword** arguments.

Answer (score 1):

render_template takes only one positional argument.
Can you try below?

```
options = {
        'margin-top': '0.15in',
        'margin-right': '0.15in',
        'margin-bottom': '0.2in',
        'margin-left': '0.15in',
        'encoding': "UTF-8",
 }
css = 'path to your .css file'
html = render_template('a_html.html')
pdf = pdfkit.from_string(html, False, options=options, css=css)
```

Comment: I got an attribute error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'app'

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running your script in the following way (I've just pasted the pdf creation part of your script into where the dash site is rendered):

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pdfkit
from flask import Flask, render_template, make_response

app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div(
                className="three columns",
                children=html.Div([
                    dcc.Graph(
                        id='right-top-graph',
                        figure={
                            'data': [{
                                'x': [1, 2, 3],
                                'y': [3, 1, 2],
                                'type': 'bar'
                            }],
                            'layout': {
                                'height': 400,
                                'margin': {'l': 10, 'b': 20, 't': 0, 'r': 0}
                            }
                        }
                    ),


                ])
            )

app.css.append_css({
    'external_url': 'https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css'
})

rendered = render_template('pdf_template.html',app)
pdf = pdfkit.from_string(rendered, False)
response = make_response(pdf)
response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=output.pdf'



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Yes I have tried that. I got the following error: render_template() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given.

I don't think this is the right approach as the pdf renderer I found only works on html objects and I currently have a dash object